# Before vs earlier

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct? Or I can use either one in the following sentence?

> He went to the restaurant even though he'd only eaten two hours [**before**/**earlier**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Latin may have a prohibition against ending a sentence with a preposition like the word ***before***, English has no such (formal) qualms.

That being said, your average English native would be more likely to use the word *earlier* as opposed to *before* if their audience expects more formal language.